# Custom papersize using floating point numbers

Tags: c#, printing

Is there any method to set paper size using real number?
I'm trying this

```
PaperSize ukuran = new PaperSize("A8", 800, 293);        
printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ukuran;
printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ukuran;
```

and it works good... the problem is when u try to print some bill repeatedly, the perforation of the printer move down and doesn't stop exactly on paper cut sign. i need to stop on A8 paper size which is 1/4 of A8 paper height per print. like this

```
PaperSize ukuran = new PaperSize("A6", 800, 292.345564); //which is A8 size
```

[image: a8 size]
<sub>(source: [designinc.co.uk](http://www.designinc.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/444px-A_size_illustration.svg_.png))</sub>

Comment: Try setting margins :            int left = 1;  //in hundreth of an inch
            int right = 1;  //in hundreth of an inch
            int top = 1;  //in hundreth of an inch
            int bottom = 1;  //in hundreth of an inch
  
            Margins margin = new Margins(left, right, top, bottom);

Comment: thanks sir, ill try that,..and ill report soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the [custom paper size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/7dbh1cyh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only takes intgers, resulting in centi-inches..

The regular solution is to pick the right [media size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.printing.pagemediasizename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the emumeration: `ISOA8 = A8`.

Which **should** work. If, as I assume, it doesn't two reasons come to mind:

- It could be a bug in GDI+ or in the driver
- your Paper might not actually be A8

Both would be hard to change.

So it may be time for a workaround: Just like our calendar inserts **leap** days and leap seconds ever now and then, you could try to calculate after how many pages you would inset a slightly larger (or smaller) **leap page**..

Sombody would probably still have to check on the printer after/before each print job to make sure it is set correctly..

Comment: i have visit link you gave me before sir,https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/us-en/library/system.printing.pagemediasizename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, but actually i don't understand how to implemented that to my code,..sorry cz im very very newbie